# Fixing GPU intensive animating frame

Tags: javascript, html, css

Thanks to [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif) we have this beautiful frame. The code works fine but unfortunately, there is an issue that made the code **completely useless**.

It cost more than 90 percent of my GPU resources! apparently my laptop getting hot in 10 seconds of running it!

Why this happens and how to fix it?

**UPDATE:** I think the issue is the code renders the animation even behind the image,
if you comment `addimage()` you can see that.

You can test it yourself:
Please [Run the code in CodePen](https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/full/mdJERWq)

And here is the code: (We add an image to the page using `addimage()` function, all the rest are CSS and HTML)

```js
addimage(); 
function addimage() {

  let pictureSource = 'https://www.architectureartdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/ArchitectureArtdesigns-8.jpg';

  var node = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
  node[0].style.background = 'url("' + pictureSource + '") center/cover'

}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin:0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.box {  
 border-radius: 10px;
  background: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, white 0 7.5px, hotpink 0 15px) 
    0 0/21.21px 21.21px;  /* 21.21px = sqrt(2) * 15px */
  animation: animate 1s linear infinite;
}

.box .content {
  width: calc(90vw - 30px);
  height: calc(85vh - 30px);  
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px deeppink, 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  margin:15px;
}


@keyframes animate {
  to {
    background-position: 21.21px 21.21px; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to run fine on my computer via the CodePen link and the snippet above.

Comment: Are you sure???!!! How could it be possible??? I'm using task manager ( windows 10 ) and I mean GPU, not CPU...

Comment: I mean, what GPU are you using? I'm experiencing my GPU going from 10% to 30% after leaving it open for a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the background-position for animation is a bit expensive. Check if the below code works fine. I just used the transform property for animation instead of background-position.

```js
addimage(); 
function addimage() {

  let pictureSource = 'https://www.architectureartdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/ArchitectureArtdesigns-8.jpg';

  var node = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
  node[0].style.background = 'url("' + pictureSource + '") center/cover'

}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: gray;
}

.box {
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background:
      repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, white 0 7.5px, hotpink 0 15px) 0 0/21.21px 21.21px;

    width: calc(100% + 21.21px);
    height: calc(100% + 21.21px);
    transform: translate(-21.21px, -21.21px);
    /* transform: translate(-15px, -15px); */
    /* transform: translate(0, 0); */
    animation: animate 1s linear infinite;


  }
.box .content {
  width: calc(90vw - 30px);
  height: calc(85vh - 30px);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px deeppink, 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  margin: 15px;
}


@keyframes animate {
  to {
    /*     background-position: 21.21px 21.21px;  */
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dropped to 25% ... Excellent job ... I wonder if the animation behind the image is using any GPU resources?